# Display log file in browser with java script

Tags: java, logging, jboss, wildfly, war

Hi I'va the next doubt and I want to know if it's possible to implement. I have some wars deployed in a wildfly/jboss server. For some reason, that server doesn't log anything and the administrator of it seems that doesn't want to do his job. So I was wondering if there's a way to see the log of each war in a browser by a frontend design by me.

I think that I can add in each war a log file, but, there's possible to access each file from a browser and see each one? Also there's no need to be in real time.

Help would be appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: If you define a logging config as part of your deployment, you can write to a suitable directory and then read that back through a suitable frontend, say a sinple servlet

Comment: refer link to configure application specific logging http://www.mastertheboss.com/jboss-server/jboss-log/using-a-logger-for-a-specific-application

Comment: @WillT thatcan be achieved even in a war? I can´t see exactly how the frontend could find that log file inside the war file.

Comment: The log file itself would be written to a regular file on the filesystem at a path of your choice. The war would just need to contain a the log config for the logging system you use, e.g log4j.properties or log4j.xml if you use log4j